# Move point in cartesian coordinate through distance in the given direction

Tags: math, geometry, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have a point in cartesian coordinate system for example :
**x = 3** & **y = 5**

And I want to get new coordinate of this point after a move through a distance in the given direction (in degrees).

How I can do for get new x and new y ?

Comment: It's an easy problem if you understand vectors.  p' = p + d*u, where p = start point, p' = end point, u = direction unit vector, d = distance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well-known formulas from the school geometry:

```
new_x = x + distance * Math.Cos(angle_degrees * Math.Pi / 180)
new_y = y + distance * Math.Sin(angle_degrees * Math.Pi / 180)
```

Note that `angle_degrees = "given direction"` is measured from the positive x-axis moving toward the positive y-axis

Comment: It should be stated that this works only if the "angle" in degrees is measured from the positive x-axis moving toward the positive y-axis.

Comment: @MBo In cartography a coordinate system is often used where 'x' points towards east, 'y' towards north, and angles are measured from the direction to the north, i.e. from the 'y' axis (sic!), in clockwise (sic!). Furthemore, if you look at the same usual cartesian plane from behind (which may happen in e.g. 3D applications), 'x' starts going to the left and angles are clockwise again (so, the formulas don't change, but the angle measurement process does). So, it is important to explicitly state the coordinate system.

Comment: I fixed the JavaScript syntax in the above answer but it got reverted? cos and sin should be lower case and PI should all be uppercase...

Comment: @Felix Eve Yes, I made rollback. Because question does not mention JavaScript. Just pseudocode.